# How to check df rows that has a difference between 2 columns and then send it to another table to verify information

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, pyodbc

I’m very new to python and am trying really hard these last few days on how to go through a df row by row, and check each row that has a difference between columns dQ and dCQ. I just said != 0 since there could be a pos or neg value. Now if this is true, I would like to check in another table whether certain criteria are met. I'm used to working in R, where I could store the df into a variable and call upon the column name, I can't seem to find a way to do it in python. I posted all of the code I’ve been playing with. I know this is messy, but any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
I've tried installing different packages that wouldn't work, I tried making a for loop (I failed miserably), maybe a function? I’m not sure where to even look. I've never learned Python, I’m really doing my best watching videos online and reading on here.

```
import pyodbc
import PyMySQL
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
                      "Server=***-***-***.****.***.com;"
                      "Database=****;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=no;"
                      "UID=***;"
                      "PWD=***")
# cur = conn.cursor()
# cur.execute("SELECT TOP 1000 tr.dQ, po.dCQ, 
tr.dQ - po.dCQ as diff FROM [IP].[dbo]. 
[vT] tr (nolock) JOIN [IP].[dbo].[vP] po 
ON tr.vchAN = po.vchCustAN WHERE tr.dQ 
!= po.dCQ")
# query = cur.fetchall()
query = "SELECT TOP 100 tr.dQ, po.dCQ/*, tr.dQ - 
po.dCQ as diff */FROM [IP].[dbo].[vT] 
tr (nolock) INNER JOIN [IP].[dbo].[vP] po ON 
tr.vchAN = po.vchCustAN WHERE tr.dQ != 
po.dCQ"
df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
#print(df[2,])

cursor = conn.cursor(PyMySQL.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 100 tr.dQ, po.dCQ/*, 
tr.dQ - po.dCQ as diff */FROM [IP].[dbo]. 
[vT] tr (nolock) INNER JOIN [IP].[dbo]. 
[vP] po ON tr.vchAN = po.vchCustAN 
WHERE tr.dQ != po.dCQ")
result_set = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result_set:
    print("%s, %s" % (row["name"], row["category"]))


# if df[3] != 0:
#     diff = df[1]-df[2]
#     print(diff)
# else:
#     exit



# cursor = conn.cursor()
# for row in cursor.fetchall():
#     print(row)
#
# for record in df:
#     if record[1] != record[2]:
#         print(record[3])
#     else:
#         record[3] = record[1]
#         print(record)

# df['diff'] = np.where(df['dQ'] != df["dCQ"])
```

I expect some sort of notification that there's a difference in row xx, and now it will check in table vP to verify we received this data's details. I believe i can get to this point, if i can get the first part working. Any help is appreciated. I'm sorry if this question is not clear, i will do my best to answer any questions someone may have. Thank you!

Comment: "I'm used to working in R, where I could store the df into a variable and call upon the column name, I can't seem to find a way to do it in python." You're already doing that. Your DataFrame is in the variable named `df`. Also be aware that PyMySQL is not relevant unless you are actually working with MySQL (and it appears that you are not).

Comment: I got it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to make a new column where you store the result of the diff between df[1] and df[2]. One note first. It might be more precise to either name your columns when you make the df, then reference them with df['name1'] and df['name2'], or use df.iloc[:,1] and df.iloc[:,2]. Also note that column numbers start with zero, so these would refer to the second and third columns in the df. The reason to use iloc is and the colons is to explicitly state that you want all rows and and column numbers 1 and 2. Otherwise, with df[1] or df[2] if your df was transposed that may actually refer to what you think of as the index. Now, on to a solution.

You could try

```
df['diff']=df.iloc[:,1]-df.iloc[:,2]
df['diff_bool']=np.where(df['diff']==0,False, True)
```

or you could combine this into one method

```
df['diff_bool']==np.where(df.iloc[:,1]-df.iloc[:,2]==0,False, True)
```

This will create a column in your df that says if there is a difference between columns one and two. You don't actually need to loop through row by row because pandas functions work like matrix math, so df.iloc[:,1]-df.iloc[:,2] will apply the subtraction row by row automatically.

Comment: This was helpful in understanding how to call upon a column in a df in python. Thank you.